# Webpack 2.0 + Karma + Test on save + hotloading

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I just upgraded my build processor from a pretty complex gulp build to webpack 2.0. Everything seems pretty straightforward, but for this particular project we need to have all our karma tests run on each save of our javascript files, while the webpack-dev-server continues to do its thing as well. I can run `webpack-dev-server`, and get my application to run and reload as I would expect in the browser, and I can run `karma start` and see all of my tests run successfully (building with webpack), I am just not sure how to marry the two so when i save, i get the hot reloading & all the tests running each time. Googling has been difficult because everything i'm finding is for webpack 1.x, and i've only done webpack for about... a day now. any suggestions for how to get this working?

Comment: Have you tried [karma-webpack](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack)? I haven't tried it with webpack 2, but I have used it with webpack 1 and it worked fine. I wouldn't recommend mixing it with what webpack-dev-server is doing, you're just adding extra complexity. Your tests and webpack-dev-server shouldn't be related anyway and having the tests run as part of development each build lifecycle is unnecessarily slowing you down. Instead, use karma with karma-webpack and leave webpack-dev-server as is.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak yes, I am using karma-webpack for running test with karma, and that is working fine- just not in tandem with the web server reloads. Typically we do not have tests run on each build, but for this particular process that is the most helpful thing for our developers.

Comment: I don't see a problem by using karma separately. If you do, please explain. I would suggest you configure to karma watch for the same code changes as webpack-dev-server and re-run tests. If it's a complex structure, you can store matched files configuration in a separate file and load it inside webpack and karma configs. After all, those are just regular node modules, nothing special is going on. Having dev-server and tests run each on their own is best of both worlds, in my opinion.